# 3D Camera coordinates to world coordinates (change of basis?)

Tags: opencv, geometry, computer-vision, linear-algebra, projective-geometry

Suppose I have the coordinates X, Y, Z and orientation Rx, Ry, Rz of an object with respect to a camera.
In addition, I have the coordinates U, V, W and orientation Ru, Rv, Rw of this camera in the world.

How do I transform the position (location and rotation) of the object to its position in the world?

It sounds like a change of basis to me, but I haven't found a clear source yet.

Answer (score 4):

I have found this document which is quite clear on the topic.
http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rcollins/CSE486/lecture12.pdf

It treats, among others, the reverse operation, i.e., going from world to camera 3D coordinates.

Pc = R ( Pw - C )
Where, Pc is a point in the camera world, Pw is a point in the normal world, R is a rotation matrix and C is the camera translation.

Unfortunately it is rather cumbersome to add latex formulae, so I will give some matlab code instead.

```matlab
function lecture12_collins()
% for plotting simplicity I choose my points on plane z=0 in this example
% Point in the world
Pw = [2 2.5 0 1]';
% rotation
th = pi/3;
% translation
c = [1 2.5 0]';
% obtain world to camera coordinate matrix
T = GetT(th, c);
% calculate the camera coordinate
Pc = T*Pw
% get the camera to world coordinate
T_ = GetT_(th, c)
% Alternatively you could use the inverse matrix
% T_ = inv(R*C)

% calculate the worldcoordinate
Pw_ = T_*Pc

assert (all(eq(Pw_ ,Pw)))


function T = GetT(th, c)
% I have assumed rotation around the z axis only here.
R = [cos(th) -sin(th) 0 0
     sin(th)  cos(th) 0 0
          0        0  1 0
          0        0  0 1];
C = [1  0   0   -c(1)
     0  1   0   -c(2)
     0  0   1   -c(3)
     0  0   0   1];
 T = R*C;

function T_ = GetT_(th, c)
% negate the angle
R_ = [cos(-th) -sin(-th) 0 0
     sin(-th)  cos(-th) 0 0
          0        0  1 0
          0        0  0 1];
% negate the translation
C_ = [1  0   0   c(1)
     0  1   0   c(2)
     0  0   1   c(3)
     0  0   0   1];
T_ = C_*R_
```

So far this is about the location only. The rotation I've solved by using extra knowledge I had of the rotation. I know that my camera is perpendicular to the object and that its rotation is only around the z axis. I can just add the rotation of the camera and the object.

Answer (score 3):

In fact you have two basis : one relative to the camera, the other is absolute (the world). So you basically want to transform your relative data into absolute data.

**Location**

This is the easiest one. You have to translate the (X,Y,Z) position by the vector t(U,V,W). So all your positions in absolute are (Ax, Ay, Az) = (X,Y,Z)+t = (X+U,Y+V,Z+W).

**Orientation**

This is a bit more difficult. You have to find the rotation matrix that rotate your camera from (I assume) (0,0,1) to (Ru,Rv,Rw). You should look at [**Basic Rotation Matrices**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) in order to decompose the 2 rotations that take (0,0,1) to (Ru,Rv,Rw) (one according to X axis, one according to Z axis for example). I advise you to draw the absolute basis and the vector (Ru,Rv,Rw) on a sheet of paper, it is the simplest way to get the right result.

So you have 2 basic rotations matrices r1 and r2. The resultant rotation matrix r = r1*r2 (or r2*r1, it doesn't matter). So the absolute orientation of your object is (ARx, ARy, ARz)
= r*(Rx,Ry,Rz).

Hope this helps !