# Convert grid of dots in XY plane from camera coordinates to real world coordinates

Tags: camera, computer-vision, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry

I am writing a program. I have, say, a grid of dots on a piece of paper. I fix one end and bend the paper toward the screen, giving me a trapezoidal shape from the camera's point of view. I have the (x,y) camera coordinate of each dot. Is there a simple way I can change these (x,y) to real life (x,y) which should give me a rectangle? I have the camera/real (x,y) of the original flat sheet of paper pre-bend if that helps.

I have looked at [3D Camera coordinates to world coordinates (change of basis?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210424/3d-camera-coordinates-to-world-coordinates-change-of-basis#) and [Transforming screen coordinates from security camera to real world coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941881/transforming-screen-coordinates-from-security-camera-to-real-world-coordinates).

Comment: Some more info about the language, implementation you made and problems you faced would help.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "homography". The transformation from a plane in 3D space to its image as captured by an ideal pinhole camera is a homography. It can be represented as a 3x3 matrix H that transforms the 3D coordinates X of points in the world to their corresponding homogeneous image coordinates x:

```
x =  H * X
```

where X is a 3x1 vector of the world point coordinates, and x = [u, v, w]^T is the image point in homogeneous coordinates.

Given a minimum of 4 matches between world and image points (e.g. the corners of a rectangle) you can estimate the parameters of the matrix H. For details, look up "DLT algorithm". In OpenCV the routine to use is `findHomography`.